# Require não esta conseguindo buscar o arquivo

Tags: php, require

Olá, no require acontece esse erro:

```
Warning: require(./funcs/FuncSQL.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Lucktor/pages/home.php on line 42

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './funcs/FuncSQL.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Lucktor/pages/home.php on line 42
```

Porem como podem ver na imagem abaixo ele esta lá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu configuro o caminho assim

```
define ("DIR_PAGES", DIR.'pages/');
```

E chamo desta forma:

```
require DIR_FUNCS.'FuncSQL.php';
```

Comment: E vc ta chamando o arquivo `FuncSql.php` dentro de `pages/home.php`? Se sim, tente `../funcs/FuncSql.php`. Ou use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].funcs/FuncSQL.php`

Comment: Quando eu tentei `../funcs/FuncSQL.php` não mudou nada e quando eu usei `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].funcs/FuncSQL.php` apenas apareceu mais erros.

Comment: Isso é erro de direcionamento... Tente fazer o seguinte teste... faz `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/funcs/FuncSQL.php'` e vê se o diretorio que ele mostrar esta correto... No meu comentario anterior eu esqueci de coloca a `/ <- barra` antes de `funcs`, deve ser por isso do erro. Mas esse erro é de apontamento errado de include do arquivo.

Comment: Acho que descobri o problema, ele esta retornando `/opt/lampp/htdocs/funcs/FuncSQL.php`, e deveria retornar `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Lucktor/funcs/FuncSQL.php`

Comment: Normalmente o `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` traz o caminho até a pasta raiz. Se resolveu o problema fecha a pergunta.

Comment: @MaxRogério Eu usei desta forma `require '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Lucktor/funcs/FuncSQL.php';` e continua retornando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53812/discussion-between-lucas-carezia-and-max-rogerio).